# Removing string from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have URLs in the form of `example.com/pages/page1` and `/example.com/pages/page2`

Is there an easy way in `.htaccess` to get rid of the `/pages/` section, so my URLs are:

```
example.com/page1
```

Thanks

Comment: Wait - please clarify so I understand your goal: Do you want your end-users typing in `example.com/pages/page1` which redirects internally to `example.com/page1` or do you want your end-users typing in `example.com/page1` which redirects internally, silently to `example.com/pages/page1`?

Comment: I want users who type `example.com/pages/page1` to be redirected to `example.com/page1` etc

Comment: See edits to my answer. Hope this does it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ability to modify the `DocumentRoot`, it sounds like you would just need to set your `DocumentRoot` to `/path/to/pages`.  However, if you can't do that then you can try this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above is generic and redirects everything to `/pages`.  If your pages really are called "page1 page2 etc", then this is more specific:

```
RewriteRule ^/page([0-9]+)$ /pages/page$1 [L,QSA]
```

Remove the `[L]` if you have more rewrite rules to process.  The `[QSA]` forwards along any other querystring parameters that may have been present.

**EDIT**: For users to enter `example.com/pages/page1` to be redirected to `example.com/page1`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above will redirect internally but not change the browser's address bar. If you want the address bar to change, informing the user that the redirect has happened, use `[L,R=301,QSA]` instead.

Comment: My page names are dynamic, so are similar to `/pages/about-us` and `/pages/contact`. I have other pages, such as `/categories` and `/users` so I'd rather not redirect everything, just those that match `/pages/dynamic_url`