# Duplicate wordpress pages - I need to strip the -2/ suffix from duplicate pages using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, duplicates

Frustrating because it seems like it should be simple.

Client had a data snaffu and a lot of merged pages in Wordpress.

domain.com/king-2
domain.com/king

are the same page.

Client wants to redirect all the -2 pages to the non -2 pages

So:

domain.com/king-2 -> domain.com/king

How could i use .htaccess to set up a rule to do this for all -2 pages?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Why not fix the source of the problem rather than working around it?
You can run an SQL find-and-replace on `post_name` (in `wp_posts`) to fix your slugs.

Comment: Seems like SQL find and replace would be a risky way to go. A .htaccess statement can be undone easily.

Comment: Make a backup if you're not 100% sure. If you really don't want to fix the problem but work around it instead, this is the real question you want to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976814/removing-string-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Im not sure that link helps me much. It discusses changing paths and what I want to do is remove a couple of trailing characters...